# Image does not load by contnent script with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, add-on

In a Chrome extension I try to load an image with a content script using CSS. The image does not load.

Here is the **manifest.json**:

```
"content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
     "css": ["content.css"],
     "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
   }
 ]
```

With the **content.js** I add an element to pages which indeed it successfully gets added every time.

And here is the **CSS code**:

```
#my_added_element {
    background: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/icon.png') right center;
}
```

I also tried:

```
#my_added_element {
    background: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/content/icon.png') right center;
}
```

in case there was a restriction about loading resources from another directory.

In both cases the CSS script gets injected as expected, as I can confirm using the developer tools, and if I click on the image's CSS link in the developer tools it opens without issues in a new tab.

So what prevents the load of the image in pages? What else should I check?

Comment: You should list it in web_accessible_resources in manifest.json.

Comment: Once again spot on! Once again thanks!